# How do you pipe a long string to /dev/stdin via child_process.spawn() in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to execute Inkscape by passing data via `stdin`. Inkscape only supports this via `/dev/stdin`. Basically, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
echo "<sgv>...</svg>" | inkscape -z -f /dev/stdin -A /dev/stdout
```

I don't want to have to write the SVG to disk.

I tried just using `stdin.write()`, but it doesn't work (maybe because of `/dev/stdin`):

```
var cmd = spawn("inkscape", ["-z", "-f", "/dev/stdin", "-A", "/dev/stdout"], {encoding: "buffer", stdio: ["pipe", stdoutPipe, "pipe"]});

cmd.stdin.write(svg);
```

This does work, but I have to write the SVG to disk:

```
var cmd = spawn("inkscape", ["-z", "-f", "/dev/stdin", "-A", "/dev/stdout"], {encoding: "buffer", stdio: [fs.openSync('file.svg', "a"), stdoutPipe, "pipe"]});
```

I tried passing a stream to `stdio`, but I just keep getting `TypeError: Incorrect value for stdio stream: [object Object]`

Any ideas?

## Addendum

The examples use Inkscape, but my question applies to any arbitrary program using `/dev/stdin`.

By the way, this would work for me:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("echo \"<svg>...</svg>\" | inkscape -z -f /dev/stdin -A /dev/stdout | cat", function (error, stdout, stderr) {});
```

Except, my SVG is too long, so it throws an error: `Error: spawn Unknown system errno 7`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I figured out a work around. This seems like a bit of a hack, but it works just fine.

First, I made this one line shell script:

```
cat | inkscape -z -f /dev/stdin -A /dev/stdout | cat
```

Then, I simply spawn that file and write to the stdin like this:

```
cmd = spawn("shell_script");

cmd.stdin.write(svg);
cmd.stdin.end();
cmd.stdout.pipe(pipe);
```

I really think this should work without the shell script, but it won't (for me at least). This may be a Node.js bug.

Answer (score 9):

Alright, I don't have Inkscape, but this appears to solve the Node.js side of things. I'm using `wc` as a stand in Inkscape; the `-c` option simply outputs the number of bytes in a given file (in this case `/dev/stdin`).

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

/**
 * Create the child process, with output piped to the script's stdout
 */
var wc = child_process.spawn('wc', ['-c', '/dev/stdin']);
wc.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

/**
 * Write some data to stdin, and then use stream.end() to signal that we're
 * done writing data.
 */
wc.stdin.write('test');
wc.stdin.end();
```

The trick seems to be signaling that you're done writing to the stream. Depending on how large your SVG is, you may need to [pay attention to backpressure](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain) from Inkscape by handling the `'drain'` event.

---

As for passing a stream into the `child_process.spawn` call, you instead need to use the `'pipe'` option, and then pipe a readable stream into `child.stdin`, as shown below. I know this works in Node v0.10.26, but not sure about before that.

```
var stream = require('stream');
var child_process = require('child_process');

/**
 * Create the child process, with output piped to the script's stdout
 */
var wc = child_process.spawn('wc', ['-c', '/dev/stdin'], {stdin: 'pipe'});
wc.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

/**
 * Build a readable stream with some data pushed into it.
 */
var readable = new stream.Readable();
readable._read = function noop() {}; // See note below
readable.push('test me!');
readable.push(null);

/**
 * Pipe our readable stream into wc's standard input.
 */
readable.pipe(wc.stdin);
```

Obviously, this method is a bit more complicated, and you should use the method above unless you have good reason to (you're effectively implementing your own readable string).

*Note: The `readable._push` function must be implemented according to the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size_1), but it doesn't necessarily have to do anything.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But when I run either of these scripts, I get "Error: write EPIPE", but they work if I remove '/dev/stdin/' from the array. I'm running v0.10.26. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What OS are you running on? I just double checked on my system (Macbook Pro running OS X 10.9.2) and both scripts ran fine. Do you have `wc` installed?

Comment: Interesting. I'm using Ubuntu. I do have `wc` installed. The commands work fine if I remove `/dev/stdin`. Maybe I'll report this as a bug.

Comment: Very interesting, I'm going to do some digging and if I find anything I'll follow back up.

Answer (score 5):

The problem comes from the fact that file descriptors in node are sockets and that linux (and probably most Unices) won't let you open /dev/stdin if it's a socket.

I found this explanation by bnoordhuis on https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3530#issuecomment-6561239

The given solution is close to @nmrugg's answer :

```
var run = spawn("sh", ["-c", "cat | your_command_using_dev_stdin"]);
```

After further work, you can now use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/posix-pipe module to make sure that the process sees a stdin that is not a socket.

look at the 'should pass data to child process' test in this module which boils down to

```
var p = pipe()
var proc = spawn('your_command_using_dev_stdin', [ .. '/dev/stdin' .. ],
    { stdio: [ p[0], 'pipe', 'pipe' ] })
p[0].destroy() // important to avoid reading race condition between parent/child
proc.stdout.pipe(destination)
source.pipe(p[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Inkscape bug 171016](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/171016) indicates, Inkscape does not support importing via stdin, but it is on their Wishlist.

Comment: It doesn't support it directly, but you can use /dev/stdin. The second example works fine and doing something like "cat file.svg | inkscape -z -f /dev/stdin -A /dev/stdout" works too. I just can't figure out how to get node to pipe in the data.