# Spawn a mysql process to import a database using node

Tags: mysql, node.js, child-process

I'm trying to write a node script to automatically import a .sql file. I think I am misunderstanding the way to pass arguments to 'spawn'. Here's what I have:

```
var spawn    = require('child_process').spawn;
var mysqlimport = spawn('/usr/local/bin/mysql', [
    '-u' + database.user,
    '-p' + database.password,
    '-h' + database.address,
    '--default-character-set=utf8',
    '--comments',
    '<"' + fileName + '"'
]);
mysqlimport
        .stdout
        .pipe(logFile)
        .on('data', function(data) {
           console.log(data); 
        })
        .on('finish', function() {
            console.log('finished')
        })
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
mysqlimport.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
mysqlimport.on('close', function(code) {
   console.log('closing code: ' + code);
});
```

And I'm getting the error

```
stdout: ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database '<"/users/user/dumps/sqlfile.sql"
```

if I don't use the -B flag when exporting, and specify the database name, changing

```
'<"' + fileName + '"'
```

to

```
databaseName + ' <"' + fileName + '"'
```

I get this other error:

```
stdout: ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name ' theDatabase < "/users/user/dumps/sqlfile.sql"'
```

I know I must be doing something wrong with specifying the argument, but how to fix it? The node documentation around spawning child processes is confusing to me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658957/how-do-you-pipe-a-long-string-to-dev-stdin-via-child-process-spawn-in-node-js - I think you need to use mysqlimport.stdin.write( 'contents of filename' ) and mysqlimport.stdin.end()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Paul F! your solution worked. I removed the last argument from the spawn and added to my code:

```
mysqlimport.stdin.write( '\\. /Users/user/dumps/' + fileName );
mysqlimport.stdin.end();
```

So In all it looks like:

```
var mysqlimport = spawn('/usr/local/bin/mysql', [
    '-u' + database.user,
    '-p' + database.password,
    '-h' + database.address,
    '--default-character-set=utf8',
    '--comments'
]);
mysqlimport.stdin.write( '\\. /Users/user/dumps/' + fileName );
mysqlimport.stdin.end();
mysqlimport
        .stdout
        .pipe(logFile)
        .on('data', function(data) {
           console.log(data); 
        })
        .on('finish', function() {
            console.log('finished')
        })
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
```