# Use Node.js to interface with bash

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, apache

I have apache and Node.js running on Ubuntu

Is there a way to programatically check if the apache service is running with Node? If it's not running, allow Node.js to start/restart the service, also could the same code be used to run other processes like MySQL?

I'd also like to find a way to make Node execute "ps -u user" and capture the output in a js string or object

I've had a look at Node.js child processes but I can't figure it out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "exec" method of "[child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)" module to execute a command from your node app and have its output passed as a parameter to a callback function.

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

exec("ps -u user", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    var myResult = stdout;
    //doSomething
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use shelljs - https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs, which has many functions goes directly to shell and is cross-platform. ps command is not one of them, so use exec similar as with child_process.

```
require('shelljs/global');    
exec('ps -aux | grep apache')
```

With exec you could start/restart service too, however you will need to run node process as root, what's not best option. Or create usergroup specifically for apache.

To run 'ps -u user' use the same. It will return you object with all info you need about processes.

```
exec('ps -u user');
```

And than continue with output as you need.

Answer (score 0):

with spawn you can run shell scripts. So if you had a shell script written to check if a processes is running...something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157779/how-to-determine-whether-a-process-is-running-or-not-and-make-use-it-to-make-a-c) you should us spawn to run it. something like...
`var child = spawn('sh', [__dirname+'/some-status-shell-script.sh'], {env: process.env});`

Likewise you can use spawn to access your mysql db...similiar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660573/spawn-a-mysql-process-to-import-a-database-using-node)