# execute mysql dump file to create table and feed data in nodejs project

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am working on nodejs project. I have following mysql dump file. Rather go on and creating that table manually and feed data manually using mysql queries, I want to execute following dump file which will create the table and feed/insert the data in that table. **How can I do that with command?**

```
  CREATE TABLE employees (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(50),
    location varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

  INSERT INTO employees (id, name, location) VALUES
  (1, 'Jasmine', 'Australia'),
  (2, 'Jay', 'India'),
  (3, 'Jim', 'Germany'),
  (4, 'Lesley', 'Scotland');
```

**UPDATE**

I want something similar in node js like below is in Ruby on rails

[Populating database using seeds.rb](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html)

Or in Laravel is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding)

Comment: Is it something that you want to execute it one-off or do you need something to manage your database change in general?

Comment: All I need to execute that file which should create the table and insert the data. Thats all.

Comment: are you looking for a script to convert mysql data dump to a node.js seed code?

Comment: No, I want to feed data to mysql table/database.

Answer (score 8):

The way to run an SQL script is by opening a process to execute the `mysql` command-line client with the SQL script as input.

Some people try to split the SQL file, and run statements one at a time. But this doesn't work in general. There are some statements in a dump file (e.g. `DELIMITER`) that cannot be run against the server, because they're builtin commands for the `mysql` client.

Here's a past Stack Overflow question that shows how to use `child_process` to spawn the `mysql` client:

- [Spawn a mysql process to import a database using node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660573/spawn-a-mysql-process-to-import-a-database-using-node)

Answer (score 0):

A tool that you can use is the [node-db-migrate](https://github.com/db-migrate/node-db-migrate) but I don't know if it is an overkill for your purpose. In general, it is used to manage database migrations but it seems that you can dump sql files and they will be executed. Here you can find the [documentation](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Here are the steps:

```
npm install db-migrate --save
npm install db-migrate-mysql --save
mkdir migrations
```

After that, you have to create a config file that will manage your database connections in different environments (the default name that the module will look for is `database.json`). It should be something like that:

```
{
  "dev": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "database": "your_db",
    "driver": "mysql",
    "user": "db_user",
    "password": "your_pass"
  },
  "prod": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "database": "your_db",
    "driver": "mysql",
    "user": "db_user",
    "password": "your_pass"
  }
}
```

After that, you have to create the migration file:

```
node_modules/.bin/db-migrate create employees-seed --sql-file
```

The command above will create the following files:

```
migrations/20161026123242-employees.js
migrations/sqls/20161026123242-employees-up.sql
migrations/sqls/20161026123242-employees-down.sql
```

You just need to dump your sql commands into the sql files and run the migrations like that. (Possibly you have to split your mysql commands into different migrations files):

```
node_modules/.bin/db-migrate up
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the dump file into one big string in node, and run it with your mysql driver in a single command. The driver should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be already a NPM module to integrate with MySql

Check this out https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/